# How to add a specific class to appended LI which is loaded via ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code. What I am trying to do is add a class "featured" to the first li item which gets added to this UL however, when I try this code, it does not work, it always add the class to every li inserted, while I want the class to be added only if there are no li in the ul and to the first li element added to this UL.

My code:

```
$(".img_add").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('input:submit, p.upload-result').hide(); // hide submit button + results while working
    $(this).parent().after('<p class="loading"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/loading_2.gif" alt="" /></p>');
    var path_img = $("#img_url").val();
    var count_images_lib = $(".upload-images-lib").length;
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ajax/add_image_url.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { path : path_img },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $('.loading').remove();
            $('input:submit').show();
            if (data.status) {
                $('.upload-images-lib').prepend(data.message);
                if (count_images_lib == 1) {
                    $('.upload-images-lib li:first-child').addClass('featured');
                }
                alert(count_images_lib);
                $('p.upload-result').fadeIn(500).html('<span class="success"><?php _e('Your image has been added successfully.','sofa'); ?></span>');
            } else {
                $('p.upload-result').fadeIn(500).html('<span class="error">' + data.message + '</span>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

What I want is to add the class to the first loaded li only. **Please note: data.message is actually a list item in html format.**

The problem is with count_images_lib always returning 1 and thus my class is added everytime. It is not with first/last selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this..

```
$('.upload-images-lib li:first').addClass('featured');
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is that alert(count..) always returns 1 which makes condition true on every prepending.

Comment: var count_images_lib = $(".upload-images-lib li").size(); and :first seem to fix it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the .first() function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing a prepend operation, I assume that the first item loaded will be at the bottom of the list. Therefore, use the `:last` selector to get the last item (which is first loaded) and give it the class.

```
$('.upload-images-lib li:last').addClass('featured')
```